# Current route showing null Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel. I am using Laravel 5.4. For some purpose, I need the current route. For this, I am using the following code in my controller.

```
  $name = Route::currentRouteName();

  dd($name);
```

But, its always showing null. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you show more code for me to check it =)

Comment: did you define route name in route file??

Comment: I had the same problem, the answer in this post solved it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46314267/route-not-working-on-laravel-5-4

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's problem with your code but you can get URL of current route with following way as well,

```
$name = URL::current();
```

To view value you can dump `$name`,

```
dd($name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following:

```
$name = Route::current()->getName();
dd($name)
```