# Route not working on laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, breadcrumbs

I am using laravel 5.4 and davejamesmiller laravel breadcrumbs version 3.0.3. Inside routes/breadcrumbs.php i am using `Route::currentRouteName()` but any `Route::...` is not returning value. instead it returns null.How can i call `Route::currentRouteName()` in there?

Comment: Try Request::path() to get the url

Comment: Have you definitely named the route?

Comment: Great. Let me post the explanation as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Route::currentRouteName()` method returns the `name` of a `named` route. This returns `null` because you don't have a named `route`.

To use this method, give the route a name using the `name()` method on the route.

```
Route::get('foo/bar',function(){
dd(Route::currentRouteName()); // null
});

Route::get('foo/bar',function(){
dd(Route::currentRouteName()); // baz
})->name('baz');
```

Then you can call `route(Route::currentRouteName())` to get the full `url` to the route like `http://localhost:8000/foo/bar`

Or

Call the `Request::path()` to get the request path of the url like `foo/bar`